# How to specify JVM SSL arguments for embedded certs?

Tags: java, ssl, command-line

Let's say I have the following JAR:

```
myapp-1.0.jar/
    META-INF/
        MANIFEST
    classes/
        com/
            <All my .class files>
        mycert1.cer
        mycert2.cer
        mycert3.cer
```

I need a way to run the JAR from the command line like so:

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=myapp-1.0.jar/classes/mycert1.cer
```

or:

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=myapp-1.0.jar/classes/mycert2.cer
```

But since the JAR is a ZIP file I can't seem to access the "embedded" SSL cert from the command line. This solution needs to work on both Windows and Linux. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of 'javax.net.ssl.keyStore' is a filename.

Resources in JAR files aren't files.

You can't do this via system properties.

You will have to get an InputStream for the resource, and load a KeyStore from it, and initialize a KeyManager with that, and initialize an SSLContext with that, and get an SSLSocketFactory from that, and create your SSLSockets with that, as described in the JSSE Reference Guide.